# Using a substring function along with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML that can appear but only one at a time:

```
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">1 - 100</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">101 - 200</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">201 - 300</a>
```

and I used this code to get the range:

```
var $field = $('#menuRange');
var nums = $field.text().split('-').map(function (a) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) + d * 100
});
```

Now I want to change the HTML into:

```
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">Lines 1 - 100</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">Lines 101 - 200</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#">Lines 201 - 300</a>
```

How can I make it so I still get nums data like before. In other words, how
can I make it ignore the word "Lines " as though it was not there?

Comment: You should consider using `unique ID` for different elements.

Comment: One only of the lines will appear in a page at once. thanks

Comment: @Joy there is a hidden gotcha that apparently only one of those elements is on the page at a time

Comment: @Gemma, Then it's fine, I didn't get that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want complete freedom in what you put in the anchors' content move the value used by your code for calculations into an attribute. Then you can change your mind about the content the user sees without needing to change your JS code at all:

```
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#" data-lines="1-100">Lines 1 - 100</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#" data-lines="101-200">Anything here</a>
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#" data-lines="201-300">still works</a>

var $field = $('#menuRange');
var nums = $field.attr("data-lines").split('-').map(function (a) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) + d * 100
});
```

You could opt for separate attributes for the min and max:

```
<a id="menuRange" class="button" href="#" data-min="1" data-max="100">Lines 1 - 100</a>
```

And then you could retrieve them separately rather than splitting out from a single string:

```
var min = $field.attr("data-min"),  // to get it as a string
    max = $field.attr("data-max");  // use .attr()
// OR
var min = $field.data("min"),       // to have jQuery automatically convert
    max = $field.data("max");       // it to a number use .data()
```

Answer (score 5):

Just put a `.substring()` after `.text()`:

```
var nums = $field.text().substring(6).split('-')...
```

i.e. just cut out the first 6 characters of the returned text.

Alternatively, if the prefix isn't always there:

```
var nums = $field.text().replace(/^Lines /, '').split('-')
```